# How to reduce flutter app apk size when using agora rtc engine and agora uikit

Tags: flutter, apk, agora

building a dating site in flutter which is using agora libraries
**flutter version 3.10.5
jdk 18
gradle 7.5 (gradle properties)**
app gradele dependecies are

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

here are flutter dependancy list

```
dependencies:
  agora_rtc_engine: ^6.1.1
  agora_uikit: ^1.3.3
  awesome_snackbar_content: ^0.1.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  cloud_firestore: ^4.5.0
  country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
  crop_image: ^1.0.5
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  easy_localization: ^3.0.1
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  google_sign_in:
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
  flutter_callkit_incoming: ^2.0.0
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.11
  flutter_flushbar: ^0.0.2
  flutter_geocoder: ^0.2.2-nullsafety
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
  flutter_mapbox_autocomplete: ^2.0.0
  flutter_ringtone_player: ^3.2.0
  flutter_swiper_null_safety: ^1.0.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.13.5
  image: ^4.0.16
  image_cropper: ^3.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+3
  in_app_purchase: 3.1.5
  location: ^4.4.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.14
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  provider: ^6.0.5
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.4
  share_plus: ^6.3.2
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  swipable_stack: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10
  uuid: ^3.0.7
```

**when i build apk with **

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64 --analyze-size  --release
```

the output comes:

```
app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (total compressed)                               53 MB
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
  META-INF/
    CERT.SF                                                                49 KB
    CERT.RSA                                                              1018 B
    MANIFEST.MF                                                            44 KB
  assets/
    dexopt                                                                  2 KB
    flutter_assets                                                          1 MB
  classes.dex                                                               3 MB
  classes2.dex                                                              3 MB
  lib/
    arm64-v8a                                                              43 MB
    Dart AOT symbols accounted decompressed size                            9 MB
      package:flutter                                                       4 MB
      package:image                                                       778 KB
      package:hookup4u2                                                   423 KB
      dart:core                                                           326 KB
      dart:ui                                                             277 KB
      package:agora_rtc_engine                                            255 KB
      dart:typed_data                                                     215 KB
      package:vector_graphics_compiler                                    170 KB
      dart:io                                                             170 KB
      dart:collection                                                     158 KB
      dart:async                                                          148 KB
      dart:ffi                                                             84 KB
      package:petitparser                                                  75 KB
      package:collection/
        src                                                                63 KB
      package:agora_uikit                                                  63 KB
      dart:convert                                                         61 KB
      package:firebase_auth_platform_interface                             58 KB
      package:vector_math                                                  55 KB
      package:intl                                                         49 KB
      package:google_mobile_ads                                            48 KB
  AndroidManifest.xml                                                       8 KB
  res/
    04.png                                                                  2 KB
    1Q.xml                                                                  1 KB
    1k.png                                                                126 KB
    1r.png                                                                126 KB
    27.png                                                                  2 KB
    33.9.png                                                                2 KB
    4F.png                                                                126 KB
    51.9.png                                                                2 KB
    5V.png                                                                  2 KB
    7r.png                                                                  1 KB
    Aj.xml                                                                  1 KB
    CG.png                                                                 13 KB
    D2.png                                                                  9 KB
    D4.png                                                                  2 KB
    E9.png                                                                  9 KB
    EA.png                                                                126 KB
    EL.png                                                                  1 KB
    ER.9.png                                                                2 KB
    EW.xml                                                                  1 KB
    FM.9.png                                                                1 KB
    FU.png                                                                  1 KB
    Fc.png                                                                  3 KB
    Fo.png                                                                126 KB
    GY.png                                                                  5 KB
    Gr.png                                                                 28 KB
    Hg.png                                                                  2 KB
    J6.9.png                                                                2 KB
    JQ.png                                                                  3 KB
    Ji.png                                                                149 KB
    L1.png                                                                149 KB
    LN.xml                                                                  1 KB
    LY.png                                                                149 KB
    Mr.9.png                                                                1 KB
    Mt.xml                                                                  1 KB
    Ov.png                                                                  2 KB
    Pi.9.png                                                                3 KB
    Q11.9.png                                                               3 KB
    Q2.png                                                                  8 KB
    Rg.xml                                                                  1 KB
    SD.png                                                                  3 KB
    Tx.9.png                                                                1 KB
    VN.png                                                                 18 KB
    Vq.png                                                                  1 KB
    YM.9.png                                                                1 KB
    _R.png                                                                  7 KB
    _c.png                                                                  1 KB
    aO.9.png                                                                1 KB
    b8.png                                                                 11 KB
    cQ.png                                                                149 KB
    color-v23                                                               2 KB
    color                                                                   5 KB
    d4.png                                                                  1 KB
    e1.xml                                                                  1 KB
    eB.9.png                                                                2 KB
    eh.png                                                                  5 KB
    g-.png                                                                 11 KB
    gA.xml                                                                  2 KB
    gV.9.png                                                                1 KB
    hI.mp3                                                                166 KB
    jZ.9.png                                                                1 KB
    jy.png                                                                  5 KB
    kX.png                                                                 26 KB
    le.png                                                                  2 KB
    m3.9.png                                                                1 KB
    oL.png                                                                  6 KB
    p4.png                                                                  4 KB
    ra.png                                                                149 KB
    rc.png                                                                  1 KB
    sB.png                                                                126 KB
    tI.png                                                                  1 KB
    tj.9.png                                                                2 KB
    u3.png                                                                  2 KB
    wi.9.png                                                                2 KB
    wi1.9.png                                                               1 KB
    y6.png                                                                  1 KB
    yB.xml                                                                  1 KB
```

tried to find the actual size occupied by each library with running devtools
output:
[image]

**you can see arm64-v8a is much bigger
could you please suggest me how can i reduce the apk size overall**
thanks in advance

[sorry for my bad english]

Answer (score 1):

So the best way to go would be to use an Android App Bundle instead of an APK for delivering your application. That way the Play Store will only add the necessaries libraries to the delivered app always ensuring the smallest size as possible (although the bundle itself may be larger sometimes).

If you are forced to use APK because you are distributing your app trough other channels than the Play Store (i.e. Firebase distribution or App Center) than you could try to add, in the application tag of your app manifest, the property `android:extractNativeLibs="true"`.

This will reduce the size of your APK although slightly increase the size of the installed app. With this parameter set to true the native libraries (`arm64-v8a` is a native lib) will be compressed in the generated APK and the total size will be reduced.

```
<application
    android:label="Welcome+"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true">
```